# Spotify Naming Conventions

Tags: spotify

Good morning all,

I am working on a software that will match spotify tracks against an external databse of songs and am having some issues with the matching (mainly with Feat., Remix etc.)

Does anyone know all the naming conventions Spotify use for track names returned by the Web API?

I am also after the Artist naming conventions as although these appear to be fairly standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those naming conventions aren't set by Spotify, but by the content provider, so there's no formal specification from Spotify.

One way you could approach this problem is to store the track name whenever there's an error and learn (possibly even machine learn) the conventions from that data.

Hope that helps!

Comment: From what I have seen you are right on this. I have started a automated system that will log any unmatched songs and I will just have to look over it manually. Eventually I should have all the different formats sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The app I’m developing ran into the same problems.
What I’ve done:

Part One:
- create 2 and variables for title, artists and album. 
One light cleaned one
One hard cleaned one
- try searching and If fail then try the alt versions

Part Two;
- adjust the query tag keys:
If using track:song+name artist:artist+name
Try changing song: or artist: to 
name:   Or even looser not using the tag at all

Part Three;
-developed a matching, scoring and filtering system
Once I have an array of potential matches I iterate they them
Have 5 scoring variables 
- title, artist, album
- duration 
- has preview URL 
I then have 3 overall scores that I’ve weighted 
To me it’s not so important that the album doesn’t match
But title, duration are important for the match 
And for my app if it has a preview URL I can use.
- naming total score 
- name and duration total score 
- naming, duration and preview total score.

I the. Sort them by the last one.
And select the top one.

It’s all not perfect and I’ve even gone further to have a
Search await page.  Where I can manually adjust/clean the
Text.   Change the search modes (tags)
Search google to see if it’s names wrong 
Search the Spotify app for same thing
And even just grab the Spotify URI and enter it into my app.

Then I realized after getting some of these custom adjustments to work.  I developed a way of saving the “search modes” and when a track is loaded it gets it’s ID and loads it into my searcher before it searches.

I’ve also added a match editor, so If my app did pick the right top track I can look at the alts, the match scores and pick and new “top track” .

And again saving this match editing history for the track to automatically load the match that I’ve picked next time!